# Call a module in a loop

Tags: r, shiny, module

I have created a module called "mod-platetab.R":

```
# Load libraries --------
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(DT)


# Define UI --------
platetab_ui <- function(id, treatment_choices) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(ns("treatment_name"), "", choices = treatment_choices)
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotlyOutput(ns("plate_plot")),
        dataTableOutput(ns("plate_metadata"))
      )
    )
  )
  
}

# Define Server --------
platetab_server <- function(id, metadata, variable, treatment_choices) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    # Define function to create plotly plot of plate
    plate_plot <- function(data, variable, treatment_choices) {
      
      colors <- brewer.pal(n = 12, name = "Set3")[1:length(treatment_choices)]
      
      # Create plotly plot 
      plot <- plot_ly(
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "markers",
        x = data$col,
        y = data$row,
        marker = list(size = 30, 
                      color = "white", 
                      line = list(color = "black",width = 2)),
        showlegend = FALSE
      )
      
      # Add axis labels and remove grid lines
      plot <- plot %>% layout(
        xaxis = list(title = "Column"),
        yaxis = list(title = "Row", autorange="reversed"),
        plot_bgcolor = "lightgrey",
        margin = list(l = 40, r = 40, b = 40, t = 40),
        hovermode = "closest",
        dragmode='select'
      )
      
      # Create plotly plot with one scatter trace for each treatment_choice
      
      for (i in 1:length(treatment_choices)) {
        subset_data <- data %>% filter(!!sym(variable) == treatment_choices[i])
        plot <- plot %>% add_trace(
          x = subset_data$col,
          y = subset_data$row,
          marker = list(size = 30, color = colors[i]),
          showlegend = TRUE,
          name = treatment_choices[i]
        )
      }
      
      # Register the 'plotly_selected' event with the plot
      plot <- event_register(plot, 'plotly_selected')
      
      return(plot)
    }
    
    # Set up reactive values
    rv <- reactiveValues(
      current_metadata = observe(metadata)
    )
    observe(
      rv$current_metadata <- metadata()
    )
    
    # Render plate plot
    output$plate_plot <- renderPlotly({
      plate_plot(rv$current_metadata, variable, treatment_choices)
    })
    
    
    
    # Update selected wells and treatment on box selection
    observeEvent(event_data("plotly_selected"), {
      event <- event_data("plotly_selected")
      if(!is.null(event)){
        # format the column values with a leading zero if necessary
        col_values <- sprintf("%02d", event$x)
        well_values <- paste0(event$y, col_values)
        rv$current_metadata <- rv$current_metadata %>% 
          mutate(!!variable := ifelse(well %in% well_values, input$treatment_name, !!sym(variable)))
      }
    })
    
    # Render metadata table
    output$plate_metadata <- renderDataTable(
      datatable(rv$current_metadata, 
                style = "bootstrap",
                options = list(paging = FALSE,
                               searching = TRUE,
                               ordering = TRUE),
                rownames = FALSE)
    )
  })
  
}
```

This module works as expected and generates a plot that represents a 96-well plate. The user can select from a list of treatment_choices using plotly_selected. As the user makes new selections the metadata$variable column gets updated (I added a render of the metadata table to make this evident).

The code can be tested with this code:

```
platetab_demo <- function() {
  metadata = data.frame(
    row = rep(rep(LETTERS[1:8], each = 12), 1),
    col = rep(sprintf("%02d", 1:12), times = 8),
    well = paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:8], each = 12), rep(sprintf("%02d", 1:12), times = 8)),
    strain = rep(" ", 96)
  )
  variable_1 = "strain"
  treatment_choices_1 = c("OptionA1", "OptionB1", "OptionC1", "OptionD1")
  
  ui <- platetab_ui("strain", treatment_choices_1)
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    platetab_server("strain", reactive({metadata}), variable_1, treatment_choices_1)
    
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Now I want to call this module on a loop or using lapply or a similar strategy. The idea is that I have another data frame called codebook. I want to use the previous module to generate one tab for each codebook$variable.

The codebook has also information about the treatment_choices for each variable that can be accesses as `var.levels <- attr(codebook, 'levels')`. For example `treatment_choices <- var.levels[["strain"]][["label"]]` gives me the treatment_choices for the variable called "strain".

So, I need to pass each variable in codebook$variable and its treatment_choices to my module (as well as the main metadata).

I've tried many things, but at this point I am quite lost (I am only a few weeks into using shiny).

This code creates a tab for each variable, but does not call the module:

```
# Load resources --------
source("mod-platetab.R")


# Define UI --------
codebook_ui <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidPage(
    uiOutput(ns("variable_tabs"))
  )
  
}


# Define Server --------
codebook_server <- function(id, codebook, metadata) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    # Generate tab panels for each variable using for loop
    output$variable_tabs <- renderUI({
      tabs <- lapply(codebook()$variable, function(variable) {
        tabPanel(variable)
      })
      do.call(tabsetPanel, tabs)
    })
    
  }) 
  
}
```

I've tried to incorporate the module with this:

```
# Load resources --------
source("mod-platetab.R")


# Define UI --------
codebook_ui <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidPage(
    uiOutput(ns("variable_tabs"))
  )
  
}


# Define Server --------
codebook_server <- function(id, codebook, metadata) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    # Generate tab panels for each variable using for loop
    observe({
      lapply(codebook()$variable, function(variable) {
        
        # Get treatment choices for current variable
        var.levels <- attr(codebook(), 'levels')
        treatment_choices <- var.levels[[variable]][["label"]]
        
        # Generate UI for current variable
        output[[paste0(variable, "_ui")]] <- renderUI({
          platetab_ui(NS(paste0(variable, "_tab")), treatment_choices)
        })
        
        # Generate server for current variable
        platetab_server(
                   paste0(variable, "_tab"), 
                   metadata = metadata,
                   variable = variable,
                   treatment_choices = treatment_choices)
      })
    })
    
  }) 
}
```

In this case it does not render the individual tabs and gives the error: *Warning: The 'plotly_selected' event tied a source ID of 'A' is not registered. In order to obtain this event data, please add `event_register(p, 'plotly_selected')` to the plot (`p`) that you wish to obtain event data from. *
The error appears 4 times, so at least is going trough the loop (my test codebook has 4 variables).

EDIT: I am testing the code for the upper level app with this:

```
codebook_demo <- function() {
  
  require(devtools)
  source_gist(4497585)
  
  metadata = data.frame(
    row = rep(rep(LETTERS[1:8], each = 12), 1),
    col = rep(sprintf("%02d", 1:12), times = 8),
    well = paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:8], each = 12), rep(sprintf("%02d", 1:12), times = 8)),
    strain = rep(" ", 96)
  )
  
  codebook <- parse.codebook("codebook_file.txt", 
                             var.names=c('variable', 'type', 'description'), 
                             level.names=c('level','label'),
                             var.sep=', ', level.sep='= ')
  codebook <- codebook %>% filter(variable != "##")
  
  ui <- codebook_ui("x")
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    codebook_server("x", reactive({codebook}), reactive({metadata}))
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
  
}
```

And the content of the .txt file with the codebook is

```
strain, char, strain collection id
    01= Blank
    02= MG1655
    03= PHC
    04= SatA2
    05= SatA18
    06= SiaP40
    07= L2
    08= Sphnx
media, char, growth medium 
    01= Blank
    02= LB
    03= M63
aTc, num, concentration for treatment
    01= 0.0
    02= 1.0
Neu5AC, num, concentration for treatment
    01= 0.0
    02= 0.1
    03= 0.5
    04= 1.0
    05= 5.0
    06= 10.0
##, ##, ##DO NOT DELETE##
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

##### Module Refactoring

First of all, I would rewrite your module as it is a bit complicated and makes it difficult to achieve what you want to do:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(shinyjs)

platetab_ui <- function(id, choices) {
   ns <- NS(id)
   list(
      control = div(
         selectInput(ns("treatment_name"), id, 
                     choices = choices),
         id = ns("plate_control"),
         class = "plate-control"),
      output = tagList(
         plotlyOutput(ns("plate_plot")),
         dataTableOutput(ns("plate_table"))
      )
   )
}

platetab_server <- function(id, meta_data, id_var, pal) {
   moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
      session$onFlushed(function() {
         outputOptions(output, "plate_plot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
         outputOptions(output, "plate_table", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
      }, once = TRUE)
      
      current_data <- reactiveVal(meta_data %>% 
                                     as_tibble() %>% 
                                     mutate(!!id_var := NA_character_))
      
      output$plate_plot <- renderPlotly({
         dat <- req(current_data())
         ## use sym as we want to pass strings and not bare column names
         id_q <- quo(!!sym(id_var))
         pl <- plot_ly(source = id) %>% 
            layout(
               xaxis = list(title = "Column"),
               yaxis = list(title = "Row", autorange = "reversed"),
               plot_bgcolor = "lightgrey",
               margin = list(l = 40, r = 40, b = 40, t = 40),
               hovermode = "closest",
               dragmode = "select",
               showlegend = TRUE
            ) %>% 
            event_register("plotly_selected")
         nr_empty_strains <- dat %>% 
            pull(!!id_q) %>% 
            is.na() %>% 
            sum()
         if (nr_empty_strains != nrow(dat)) {
            pl <- pl %>% 
               add_trace(
                  data = dat %>% filter(!is.na(!!id_q)),
                  x = ~ col,
                  y = ~ row,
                  color = id_q,
                  colors = pal,
                  type = "scatter",
                  mode = "markers",
                  showlegend = TRUE,
                  marker = list(size = 30, 
                                line = list(color = "black", width = 2))
               ) 
         }
         if (nr_empty_strains != 0) {
            pl <- pl %>% 
               add_trace(
                  data = dat %>% filter(is.na(!!id_q)),
                  x = ~ col,
                  y = ~ row,
                  type = "scatter",
                  mode = "markers",
                  showlegend = FALSE,
                  marker = list(size = 30, 
                                color = "white",
                                line = list(color = "black", width = 2))
               )              
         }
         pl
      })
      
      observeEvent(event_data("plotly_selected", id), {
         evt <- req(event_data("plotly_selected", id))
         dat <- req(current_data())
         current_data(
            dat %>% 
               mutate(!!id_var := if_else(well %in% paste0(evt$y, evt$x),
                                          input$treatment_name,
                                          !!sym(id_var)))
         )
      })
      
      output$plate_table <- renderDataTable(
         datatable(req(current_data()),
                   options = list(paging = FALSE,
                                  searching = TRUE,
                                  ordering = TRUE),
                   rownames = FALSE)
      )
   })
}
```

Key concept is that you add a `source` field to `plot_ly` to be able to identify the corresponding `event_data`. The logic works like this, that in case there is a new `select_event` I mark the corresponding lines in `current_data` and in the `renderPlotly` function I add empty circles for unselected points and colored ones according for the selected. Colors are controled via the parameter `pals` which is a named vector of colors.

I let the `ui` function return 2 elements, the `selectInput` and the `outputs` because in the main app we want to separate them into the `sidebarPanel` and the `mainPanel`.

##### Static Data

```r
cb_orig <- "strain, char, strain collection id
    01= Blank
    02= MG1655
    03= PHC
    04= SatA2
    05= SatA18
    06= SiaP40
    07= L2
    08= Sphnx
media, char, growth medium 
    01= Blank
    02= LB
    03= M63
aTc, num, concentration for treatment
    01= 0.0
    02= 1.0
Neu5AC, num, concentration for treatment
    01= 0.0
    02= 0.1
    03= 0.5
    04= 1.0
    05= 5.0
    06= 10.0
##, ##, ##DO NOT DELETE##"

tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".txt")
cat(cb_orig, "\n", file = tf)


md <- expand.grid(
   row = LETTERS[1:8],
   col = sprintf("%02d", 1:12),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) %>% 
   as_tibble() %>% 
   mutate(well = paste0(row, col))

devtools::source_gist(4497585)

codebook <- parse.codebook(tf, 
                           var.names = c("variable", "type", "description"), 
                           level.names = c("level", "label"),
                           var.sep = ", ", level.sep = "= ")

pals <- map(attr(codebook, "levels"),
            ~ brewer.pal(n = 12, name = "Set3")[seq_len(nrow(.x))] %>% 
               set_names(.x$label))
```

Basically we creating the meta data `md` (but do not specify the special column which will come from `codebook` and dynamically added in the module) and are extracting the several choices which we want to add in the shiny app.

##### Main App

```r
uis <- imap(pals, ~ platetab_ui(.y, names(.x))) %>% 
   transpose()
tabs <- imap(uis$output, ~ tabPanel(.y, .x))

ui <- fluidPage(
   useShinyjs(),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         map(uis$control, hidden)
      ),
      mainPanel(
         do.call(tabsetPanel, c(unname(tabs), id = "tabsets", 
                                selected = names(uis$output)[[1L]]))
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   listeners <- lapply(names(pals), \(.y) platetab_server(.y, md, .y, pals[[.y]]))
   observeEvent(input$tabsets, {
      hideElement(selector = ".plate-control")
      showElement(NS(input$tabsets)("plate_control"), asis = TRUE)
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

With all this pre work the main app is rather simple. We run a loop over `pals`  which contain the colors and the names for the `selectInput` and put them into `tabPanels`. In the `UI` we put the `selectInput` in the `sidebarPanel` and the rest into the `mainPanel`.

Because we only want to show the relevant `selectInputs` (and not all of them) I chose to hide them on startup (vis `shinyjs::hidden` and unhide them on tabset change (the `outputOptions` statement in the module server makes sure that output elements which are not shown are not suspended, which would eb otherwise the default).

All what is left is to call the module server functions in the server function and add an observer which hides / shows the `selectInputs` as we change the tabs.

The added `class` and `id` attributes are there to identify the elemets to hide more easily.

*N.B.*  The app will show a warning regarding unknown `source` IDs. This is a [known artefact](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1528) and can be safely ignored.

Comment: Thanks you very much, that was awesome. I see that my code needed a full makeover! It works almost as I intended, but I realize that I was not clear enough that the reactive metadata table needs to be updated with all the new columns. Now I am getting 4 tabs in the current example and in each of them a new column gets update to metadata. But the end goal is to have a single metadata as the output that can be passed to another module on the app. This metadata should have all the new columns, not only one at a time. Any ideas about fixing that? Thanks again